# How to disable Delphi XE3 theme over TMS CurvyEdit component

Tags: delphi, themes, delphi-xe3

Help pls. The theme option in Delphi XE3 is great. Unfortunately something goes wrong when I try to use component – TMS CurvyEdit. When I'm applying bright theme on Form everything is OK. When the theme is dark TMS CurvyEdit looks quite ugly. This component is similar to standard Delphi ButtonedEdit though it looks quite nice here. The problem is that the area between buttons looks awful. I unsuccessfully tried different methods to disable applying themes over the above mentioned component. I need TMS CurvyEdit component to be always white no matter which theme is active. Any suggestions pls.?

Comment: Did you ask TMS? They offer free support for their component packs through email, forums, and newsgroups at [TMS Support](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/support.asp).

Comment: If you want help, be precise. Care about details. I don't think you mean themes. I think you mean VCL styles. Or is this FMX? How can we tell? If we have to guess, expect little useful help. And yes, talk to the vendor.